# Merge column and count it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataframe

[image]

This is the current result

[image]

The problem is that the project groups may save several different ids. I would like to output the three most liked project groups (most liked = count of project group). How could I merge the project groups with the project id and count them? I would like to count the projectgroup with the studentname when it is merged.
I would like to count how often the project group appears and it should be merged with the project id, so that there is only one project id.

```
   d = {
        'Studentid': [1, 2, 3 , 1, 1, 1, 1, 4]
        ,'Studentname': ['Bob', 'Jason', 'Jackson', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Max']
        , 'projectgroup': ['The fantastic', 'New', 'Banana' , 'The fantastic', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'New']
        ,'projectid': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    display(df)
    project_df = df.groupby('projectgroup').agg(project_list = ('projectid',set),
                                                unique_projects=('projectid','nunique'))
    
    pd.merge(project_df[['Studentid','Studentname','projectgroup']].drop_duplicates(),project_df,how='left',on='projectgroup')

   df_sorted = project_df.groupby(['projectid', 'projectgroup']).size().nlargest(3) .reset_index(name='freq_of_projects')
   display(df_sorted)
```

What I want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `nunique` on `studentid`:

```
project_df = df.groupby('projectgroup').agg(project_list = ('projectid',set),
                                            unique_projects=('projectid','nunique'),
                                            frequence=('Studentid','nunique'))
```

Output:

```
              project_list  unique_projects  frequence
projectgroup                                          
Banana              {3, 5}                2          2
New                    {2}                1          2
The fantastic       {1, 4}                2          1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got an error, when trying to use your code snippet `KeyError: "None of [Index(['Studentid', 'Studentname', 'projectgroup'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: What data frame you used it on? Definitely should run on `df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`.

Comment: thanks! First `df` then `project_df` and after that `df_sorted`